# DropDownListFor not selecting default

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems trying to get a preselected value to work. 
I've tried to include Selected in the SelectListItem but it doesn't pre-select. 
Any clues as to why it's not matching up?  Thanks for any help.

RetailerId is int. (it's not defined as enumerable)

Retailer is an enum, for example:

```
public enum Retailer
{
  Sears = 10, 
  Macys = 20
}
```

Here is the View code :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RetailerId,
                    Enum.GetValues(typeof(Retailer)).Cast<Retailer>()
                    .OrderBy(o => o.GetDescription())
                    .Select(o => new SelectListItem() { Text = o.GetDescription(), Value = o.ToString(), Selected = (o.ToInt() == Model.RetailerId) }), 
                    new { @data_placeholder = "Select Retailer", @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generating a collection of `SelectListItem` where the `Value` is either "Sears" or "Macys" which cannot be bound to property `RetailerId` which is an `int`.

Note that the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a model property. Internally the method sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the property your binding to, and since its an `int`, it does not match any of your options values and the first option is selected because something has to be.

You can make this work by modifying the `.Select` clause to

```
.Select(o => new SelectListItem() { Text = o.GetDescription(), Value = ((int)o).ToString() }),
```

Alternatively, change the model property to

```
public Retailer RetailerId { get; set; }
```

an the `.Select` clause to

```
.Select(o => new SelectListItem() { Text = o.GetDescription(), Value = o.ToString() }),
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works!  thx for the explanation!! would have loved to have known the selected property was useless from some documentation when binding.